# Google Charts Dashboard JSON Feed from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-visualization

I am creating a Google Charts dashboard that I am going to put on a [Google Site](https://sites.google.com/site/testdashboard4/) as an "Apps Script Gadget."  The dashboard will have multiple filters/charts, but I have only included one filter and one bubble chart to keep it simple at this point.  Also, the data source for the dashboard is [this Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18xblHu4aYK-iNNP0aLPNvQugi06VISmKtee-MDvc2mM/edit#gid=0).

To do this, I created a doGet() script that uses the HTMLService to return the HTML/Javascript that will be included in the Google site.  [Here is the link to the script file.](https://script.google.com/d/1_bawb4jUqAqNtf9_Ve_gOdSzAWL4K1ib7u6xgGxn6D361A6SGFsu6A94/edit?usp=drive_web) Notice that the HTMLService creates the output from "index2" (I was just testing with the "index" file).

[And here is the link to the web app.](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwsuR9odXahJYht2TLVpgBrVpkPjjN9OuQdz9S4o2GSUHQc4s87/exec)  You can see that the the current errors are:  "Table has no columns" and "One or more participants failed to draw."

I am pretty sure the issue is that the web app is not reading the JSON correctly, and as a result, the DataTable is not set (and ultimately, the dashboard cannot be drawn).  I have tried a couple of things unsuccessfully.  First, I tried to query the spreadsheet in order to create the DataTable, but I couldn't get this to work (this attempt is currently commented out in the "index2" file).  Then I tried to get the spreadsheet data as a JSON feed, but I couldn't get it to work (this is the current attempt on the "index2" file).  However, it seems that the JSON output is correct based on [this url](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/18xblHu4aYK-iNNP0aLPNvQugi06VISmKtee-MDvc2mM/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script), but perhaps it is not correct.

The snippet of code in the web app that generates the DataTable is:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/18xblHu4aYK-iNNP0aLPNvQugi06VISmKtee-MDvc2mM/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
}).responseText;

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

Clearly, the datatable is not being created correctly.  Thoughts?  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: That JSON string is not in the correct format for the Visualization API.  The Viz API provides a `Query` object that you can use to query Google Docs spreadsheets.  Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets) and give that a try.

Comment: I just changed the file after reading the documentation, but the query response throws the error:  "Invalid JSON string"...thoughts on this error?

Comment: Does it matter that the spreadsheet is a new Google Sheet?  And/or does the spreadsheet have to be published?

Comment: Yes, it works with the new spreadsheets.  Under the old spreadsheets, they had to be published; I do not know if that is the case with the new ones.

Comment: I just published it, but am still getting the same "Invalid JSON String" error.  Hmm...

Comment: What url are you using for the spreadsheet?

Comment: I am using this url:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18xblHu4aYK-iNNP0aLPNvQugi06VISmKtee-MDvc2mM/pubhtml

Comment: Right now that link shows the Google spreadsheet table...should it be in JSON format?

Comment: Use this URL: `'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18xblHu4aYK-iNNP0aLPNvQugi06VISmKtee-MDvc2mM/gviz/tq'`.

Comment: [Yup that works!](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwsuR9odXahJYht2TLVpgBrVpkPjjN9OuQdz9S4o2GSUHQc4s87/exec)...now I can incorporate CSS...thank you!

Comment: It seems like you just added "/gviz/tq" after the spreadsheet key...is it as easy as that?!?

Comment: Also, when I initially copied and pasted the URL, there was a space between the "...tee-MD" and "vc2mM...".  Do you know why that is?  I had to manually delete the space for the URL to work properly.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The URL format for the new spreadsheets is `'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq'`, where `{key}` is the unique spreadsheet key.  I have no idea why you would get a space in the URL, but there definitely should not be one.